# Create a link with an iframe thumbnail

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink, thumbnails

I am trying to make a portfolio page and am want to use a thumbnail of one of my projects (a live page) as a link to that project.  I've gotten the thumbnail made, but can't figure out how to make it a clickable link.

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="thumbnail-container">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <figure>
          <iframe src="https://codepen.io/valsburger/full/wppwmJ " scrolling="no">
          </iframe>
      </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried putting an  element around the iframe in several locations.  Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that, will cause your page to be slower and frankly is just unnecessary.

Here is a photo of the page you want to:
 [image: Your Page]
Here is the code you should use:

```
<div class="thumbnail-container">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <figure>
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y4fc.jpg">
      </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to use an <img> for the link, which I know how to do, but am using a free version of CodePen and can't upload assets. I haven't found any file hosting sites I like.

Comment: Alright hopefully it worked then, if so please mark my answer as correct thanks

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is a "window into another world". There's could be lots of links in that window. So, it would be a bad idea if you could link the iframe itself. An iframe gets embedded, you cannot link it.

And frankly, I'm not sure WHY you'd even want to link an iframe in the first place? Seems very odd to me. Why don't you link the thumbnail itself?? That would be just a normal img element.

Comment: Because I'm using a free version of CodePen and I can't upload photos.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly solution would be to place a transparent, relatively positioned `<div>` on top of the `<iframe>`, size it to cover the `<iframe>` and wrap it in `<a>` tags linking to your page. 
Although I would suggest using regular `<img>` elements as thumbnails.